# Como obter o SHA1 de uma String em Swift?

Tags: swift

Eu sei que existe o objeto `SHA1` mas ainda estou aprendendo a sintaxe, então,
minha dúvida de iniciante é, dado uma string simples:

```
var greeting = "Hello!"
```

Como obter o SHA1 de `greeting` em `Swift`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

você pode utilizar o framework de criptografia da Apple. Adicione `#import <CommonCrypto/CommonCrypto.h>` na sua classe que faz a ponte entre Objective-C e Swift (`*-Bridging-Header.h`). Assim você consegue usar o código abaixo:

```
extension String {
    func sha1() -> String! {
        let str = self.cStringUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding)
        let strLen = CUnsignedInt(self.lengthOfBytesUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding))
        let digestLen = Int(CC_SHA1_DIGEST_LENGTH)
        let result = UnsafePointer<CUnsignedChar>.alloc(digestLen)

        CC_SHA1(str!, strLen, result)

        var hash = NSMutableString()
        for i in 0..<digestLen {
            hash.appendFormat("%02x", result[i])
        }

        result.destroy()
        return String(hash)
    }
}
```

**EDIT:**
Na versão mais recente do Xcode o método `CC_SHA1` recebe parâmetros diferentes. É necessário alterar o tipo da variável `result` para um `UnsafeMutablePointer<UInt8>`

```
let result = UnsafeMutablePointer<UInt8>.alloc(digestLen)
```

E por exemplo, para usar:

```
var greeting = "Hello!"
NSLog("%@", greeting.sha1())
```

Se quiser conferir o projeto rodando na versão mais recente do Xcode 6, é só da uma olhada no exemplo que eu coloquei no GitHub:
https://github.com/xdoug/Swift-SHA1

Comment: oi @douglas-ferreira eu estou usando a versão 6.0.1 do Xcode disponível na App Store e seguindo as instruções para criara a bridge Swift-Objective C [deste link](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/swift/conceptual/buildingcocoaapps/MixandMatch.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014216-CH10-XID_76) observei que não foi oferecido a opção descrita na sessão "Importing Objective-C into Swift". Qual seria a alternativa ?

Comment: Ja tive esse problema uma vez, pode criar manualmente o arquivo de `Bridging Header`.
Adicione um arquivo de _header_ com o nome `[SeuProjeto]-Bridging-Header.h`.
No _build settings_ do seu projeto, procure por `Swift Compiler – Code Generation`e depois `Objective-C Bridging Header` e ai você coloca o caminho do seu arquivo de _header_ (`SeuProjeto/SeuProjeto-Bridging-Header.h`), por exemplo.

Comment: Valeu @douglas-ferreira. Criei a bridge mas rolou um erro no seu código Swift. Deve ter a ver com a minha versão de Xcode. O erro foi esse: `'UnsafePointer<CUnsignedChar>.Type' does not have a member named 'alloc'` na linha :  `let result = UnsafePointer<CUnsignedChar>.alloc(digestLen)`. Você tem alguma sugestão ?

Comment: Encontrei uma discussão a respeito deste problema [neste post do SO](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25130581/how-do-you-alloc-dealloc-unsafe-pointers-in-swift). Existem algumas abordagens sugeridas. Qual você acha melhor ?

Comment: A Apple fez alteração no construtor do `CC_SHA1` em um dos updates do Xcode6/Swift. Ajustando para a forma correta ficaria `let result = UnsafeMutablePointer<UInt8>.alloc(digestLen)`. Vou atualizar minha resposta.